# Kivy. Linux Ubuntu. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, kivy

Есть код, написанный в питоне на Линуксе (виртуалка):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

В итоге ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testfile.py", line 11, in <module>
MyApp().run()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 835, in run
raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

Где я согрешил и как мне покорить этого пингвина?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно возвращать объект класса Button а не сам класс

```
return Button()
```